# Simulating out of order request processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to simulate setInterval client side behavior where ajax GET requests are sent to the server and returned back out of order. For example:

```
  var ul = $('ul.log'),
            index = 0;

        setInterval(function() {
          var started = new Date(),
              i = index;

              index++;

              $.get('/date', function(date) {
                  var end = new Date();
                  ul.append('<li>Request ' + i + ' started at ' +
                            started.getHours() + ':' + started.getMinutes()
                            + ':' + started.getSeconds());
              });

        }, 1000);
```

setInterval is supposed to execute after every specified interval, so if the server is busy, responses are supposed to come out order. I tried to implement that side in NodeJS:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var i = 0;
app.get('/date', function(req, res){

  var sleep = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5) * 1000;

  setTimeout(function() {
    res.end("test string");
    i++;
  }, sleep);

});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

server = app.listen(3002, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Here I'm setting random timeout so that requests are processed out of order. However, it doesn't work(html output):

```
Request 0 started at 11:50:6
Request 1 started at 11:50:7
Request 2 started at 11:50:8
Request 3 started at 11:50:9
Request 4 started at 11:50:10
```

and I expected something like this:

```
Request 0 started at 11:50:6
Request 1 started at 11:50:7
Request 4 started at 11:50:10
Request 2 started at 11:50:8
Request 3 started at 11:50:9
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I figured that Node actually waits for setTimeout period just to execute the function, and actually blocks new requests, making this thing synchronous, weird..

Comment: Copied the code, got the requests distributed more or less randomly; are you sure there's nothing else in your server/client code? You can try this - `setTimeout((function(i) { return function(){res.end('' + i);}})(i), sleep)` - to get back the index of request as it was sent from a client.
  i++;

Comment: Don't forget the fact that you'll only see the requests in non-regular order if `setTimeout` delay distribution is significant enough to cover all the expenses for Node internal operations. Currently, its range is 5-9 sec. How about increasing multiplier (`* 5`) instead, for like `* 10`?

Comment: Hmm... I've done some experiments on Firefox and it seems that its behaviour is drastically different from Chrome - it indeed orders all the requests regularly. WTH?

Comment: OK guys, here are the files that I'm currently using http://runnable.com/VBGSMJVsiLQo_odg/nodejs-for-node-js-and-hello-world I'm still getting the same ordered result, could you run this ? I'm using Chrome if that means anything...

Comment: Just tried in IE, and it works!!

Comment: Seems to be the problem of caching. All works well if you query for `'/date?' + Math.random()` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61054/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-zed).